# how to read attribute value in json using android

Tags: android, json

I want to read json attribute value, my json format like this

```
{"content":{"@attributes" : { "start_limit" : "x","end_limit" : "x","total_records" : "x"},"item":[{"category":"x","distance":"x"}]}},
```

I want to read total_record's value from json attributes. How can I read ? Please help me

Thanks
John Rick

Answer (score 4):

First of all check your JSON String.Change it to

`{"content":{"@attributes" : { "start_limit" :"x","end_limit" : "x","total_records" : "x"}},"item":[{"category":"x","distance':"x"}]}}` from

`{"content":{"@attributes" : { "start_limit" : "x","end_limit" : "x","total_records" : "x"},"item":[{"category":"x","distance":"x"}]}}`

In which you left one closing curly brace before "item".

Now below is the code to get value of "total_records"

```
String jsonString = "{'content':{'@attributes' : { 'start_limit' :'x','end_limit' : 'x','total_records' : 'x'}},'item':[{'category':'x','distance':'x'}]}}";

public String getTotalRecords(String jsonString){
    try {
            JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONObject contentObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("content");
            JSONObject attributesObject = contentObject.getJSONObject("@attributes");
            String totalRecords = attributesObject.getString("total_records");
            Log.i("Total Records", totalRecords);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return totalRecords;
}
```

Hope you understand the problem.

Comment: should be accepted as the correct answer! Thanks, was looking for this too :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply use [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(src);
String totalRecs = obj.getString("total_records");
```

Not 100% sure it works, but it is a good example where to start.

Comment: @Thanks for your reply,can u give some example for get value from total_records from json

Comment: You're code assumes `total_records` is a property of the top level object, which it isn't.

Comment: @RoToRa, I haven't written, that is a solution. Just pointed the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you've already given it a try before asking in SO. If not, here are a few urls (which I googled):
http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/ and http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/03/androind-json-parser.html