# Parsing data from JSON

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

Ok so I got here is my sample JSON:

```
{
    "messages":[
    {
        "receiver":"60:51:2c:93:6e:02",
        "sender":"60:51:2c:93:6e:01",
        "location":[
        {
            "longitude":"26.89478",
            "latitude":"122.779953"
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
    ,"isSuccess":"true"
}
```

How can I retrieve every data inside it?

This is only what I got:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = parser.makeHttpRequest(someurl);
JSONArray messages = jsonObject.getJSONArray("messages");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read attribute value in json using android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469034/how-to-read-attribute-value-in-json-using-android)

Comment: which value do you want?

Comment: @VD' the sender, longitude, latitude and isSuccess

Comment: study this link : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ , You will properly understand how to parse json.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the org.json lib

```
String json = "{\"messages\":[{\"receiver\":\"60:51:2c:93:6e:02\",\"sender\":\"60:51:2c:93:6e:01\",\"location\":[{\"longitude\":\"26.89478\",\"latitude\":\"122.779953\"}]}],\"isSuccess\":\"true\"}";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        Boolean isSuccess = jsonObject.getBoolean("isSuccess");
        JSONArray messages = jsonObject.getJSONArray("messages");
        JSONObject firstElement = messages.getJSONObject(0);
        String sender = firstElement.getString("sender");
        JSONArray locationArray = firstElement.getJSONArray("location");
        JSONObject firstLocation = locationArray.getJSONObject(0);
        Double lng = firstLocation.getDouble("longitude");
        Double lat = firstLocation.getDouble("latitude");

        Log.d("Result", "isSuccess: " +  String.valueOf(isSuccess)
                +"\n Sender: " + String.valueOf(sender)
                +"\n Latitude: " + String.valueOf(lat)
                +"\n Longitude: " + String.valueOf(lng));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Or with less lines of code

```
        Boolean isSuccess = jsonObject.getBoolean("isSuccess");
        String sender = jsonObject.getJSONArray("messages").getJSONObject(0).getString("sender");
        JSONObject firstLocation = jsonObject.getJSONArray("messages").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("location").getJSONObject(0);
        Double lng = firstLocation.getDouble("longitude");
        Double lat = firstLocation.getDouble("latitude");
```

What I also like with this library are the opt..() methods like optDouble() or optJSONObject() to avoid nested try/catch and define a default value if the key you are looking for doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use JSCKSON APIs

refer below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
        String json = "{\"messages\":[{\"receiver\":\"60:51:2c:93:6e:02\",\"sender\":\"60:51:2c:93:6e:01\",\"location\":[{\"longitude\":\"26.89478\",\"latitude\":\"122.779953\"}]}],\"isSuccess\":\"true\"}";
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            JsonNode node = om.readTree(json);
            System.out.println(node.get("messages").get(0).get("receiver"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```